# Square Up Item modifier a text field

Tags: square

In Square Up items in their online store it appears you can some how code your own modifiers.

I need to add a text field the user must enter data before placing the item in the cart.

I was unable to find an article about this.  Anybody know how to code this, or can point me to an article with this information.

Comment: Is this what you're referring to? https://docs.connect.squareup.com/products/catalog/overview#catalog-items-variations-and-modifiers

Comment: Yes, the modifiers listed on that page.  Though those modifiers are just selections.  The user cannot enter data into any of the modifiers.  I want them to be able to add a name into the modifier box.  Similar to the Sellers Notes on the check out window, but for the item they are adding to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

With the [UpsertCatalogObject](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-upsertcatalogobject) endpoint, you can allow your customer to add their information into a text box (that you create) so that you can create a Catalog Object of type Modifier for the transaction.